# Resize Gallery thumbnail list in android

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery

I need to increase the thumbnail size in android gallery.i tried to increase the gallery height but thumbnail size not increasing.can i resize the thumbnail image of gallery?
this is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
    android:background= "@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#fff"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />
      <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my fragments.

```
 Gallery gallery = (Gallery)rootView. findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
             gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

             gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id)
             {
             // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             // display the images selected
             ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
             imageView.setImageResource(mThumbsIds[position]);
             }
             });
```

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891909/how-to-increase-the-size-of-image-view-in-android) he asking increase the size of imageview but i want to increase the size of thumbnail view